# SQL query to populate

Tags: sql

Pls I need an SQL query to get all the columns on this (Personnel) table with: **Salary** in descending order, and for every **Employee** without a **Buddy**, replace with his **Manager**. Please help, Thanks.

[image]

The solution should look like:

[image]

Comment: Do a self join. Use coalesce().

Comment: How does Charlie Hudson with manager Liam Pulling acquire a buddy Henry Cook?

Comment: Just use the simple select statement with order by salary in decs and the add a case statement in select for buddy if the buddy is empty you can take manager name in select.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @P.Salmon where a buddy is missing, the manager of Charlie's department (IT) becomes the buddy

Comment: Then why does henry payne acquire leslie brandon when henry payne appears to be  employee and manager of sales department? Actually where does leslie brandon magically appear from? Is there a rule if employee is also manager then something else happens

Comment: It would help if you added sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

just use the simple select statement with order by salary in decs and the add a case statement in select for buddy if the buddy is empty you can take manager name in select or take the buddy name.

ie:

```
 Select Employee, Manager, Salary, EmployeeDepartment,
ManagerDepartment, case when isnull(Buddy, '') ='' Then Manager else Buddy end AS 'Buddy'
from personal_table
 order by Salary desc
```

learn some basic here ->
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm

Comment: Charlie Hudson with manager Liam Pulling acquires a buddy Henry Cook in ops desired outcome this query won't.

Comment: but as per his question when employee without a buddy we need to replace the manager ?. Its the case this query will work right!

Comment: @arunsakthivel96 yes, I'm familiar with select case. This query will give Liam Patting and not Henry Cook as Charlie's buddy. Remember they are in different rows

Comment: @greg616 As you have mentioned is Employee without Buddy replace with his manages. it means we need to replace the empty buddy's with his manages. correct me if I'm wrong !

Comment: @greg616 I Can't understand what is expectation.  1) For  empty buddy we need to Select the direct manager? 2) For empty buddy we  need to add the manager who has not add to buddy's  in these two which scenario you are expecting ?